# Editing a Blogger's blog

Tags: css, blogger

I own this blog: 
http://un-francais-a-new-york.blogspot.com/

Notice the break in the background.  I need the grey background to go all the way to the top of the page, instead of breaking where the header starts.

Here's how I need it to look like: 
[image]
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `background: grey;` to the class `content-fauxcolumns` will solve your problem.

Now promise me you'll checkout some tutorials on html and css: https://www.codeschool.com/paths/html-css

Comment: that is the css. If you look in your style sheet you'll find this `.content-fauxcolumns { ... stuff inside .. }`. Add the background property and set it to the color you'd like :  `.content-fauxcolumns { ... stuff inside ... background: grey; }`. Seriously though, take a look a the link. Maybe you'll discover a passion for it.

Comment: No problem man! Its awesome to hear you'll take a look. By the way, do me a favor and accept my answer. thanks